# Is there a way to detect multiple pan gestures?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I want the user to be able to pan from each thumb simultaneously but I can't figure out how to detect it with uigesturerecognizer.  I can detect a tap and a pan simultaneously no problem.

It appears that the second pan will block the first.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would need 2 pan recognizers. I assume you only have 1.

Comment: I do only have one.  I'll give that a try.  Thanks!

Comment: That didn't work for me.  Both pan recognizers are called when the first finger pans but as soon as the second finger pans they receive those calls only and completely ignore the first.

Comment: I think you need to explain what your trying to accomplish here a little more. How do the two pan gestures from each thumb interact with each other? Are they working together, moving the same way or moving differently?

Comment: They're independent.  One is supposed to be for moving a character and the other for change the direction it is looking.

Comment: @Xavier: How do you know which pan gesture is which? Perhaps you should use delegate callbacks (`-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`) to allow each recognizer to only see one thumb. Assuming one is on the left half of the screen and the other is on the right, you can trivially use the location of the touch to decide if the gesture recognizer should see it.

Comment: Yes this sounds like what I want. I'll try doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by defining shouldReceiveTouch like so:

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == singleTap) {
        return YES;
    }
    if (gestureRecognizer == pan1 && [touch locationInView:self].x > 160) {
        return YES;
    }
    if (gestureRecognizer == pan2 && [touch locationInView:self].x <= 160) {
        return YES;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

And initWithFrame has the following code:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];
NSLog(@"tap: %p", singleTap);

pan1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan1:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:pan1];
NSLog(@"pan1: %p", pan1);

pan2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan2:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:pan2];

for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers) {
    recognizer.delegate = self;
}
NSLog(@"pan2: %p", pan2);
```

Comment: You may also want to have a look at `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`